# Table TD are not aligning correctly

Tags: html, css

The issue I am having is for some reason, the order of a particular td skips order: The following image will show you what I mean:

As you can see below, the TEMP section should not be in the end but rather next to full time.

[image]

Below is the html and css code.

HTML:

```
<div id="mainPhoto2">
        <div
            style="display: inline-block; text-align: center; margin-left: 260px">
            <h1>
                JOB <br />
                <span class="green">AUTHORIZATION</span><span class="gray">
                    NOTICE (JAN)</span>
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div style="float: right; margin-top: 10px; margin-right: 30px">
            <cfoutput> Date Completed:<br />
            #DateFormat(now(), "mm/dd/yyyy")# </cfoutput>
        </div>
        <form name="SubmitVisit" method="POST" class="j">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4" class="mm">&nbsp;&nbsp;SECTION A - CHECK
                            CATERGORY(S) THAT APPLY AND COMPLETE APPROPRIATE SECTIONS</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="mm"><input type="checkbox" /> Replacement</td>
                        <td class="mm"><input type="checkbox" /> Additional Position</td>
                        <td class="mm"><input type="checkbox" /> New Title/Position</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4" class="mm">&nbsp;&nbsp;SECTION B - CURRENT
                            INFORMATION REQUIRED</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="mm">&nbsp;&nbsp;Department Name<br />
                        <br /></td>
                        <td class="mm" style="vertical-align: top">&nbsp;&nbsp;Location</td>
                        <td colspan="2" class="mm" style="text-align: center"><select
                            class="selectmenu2">
                                <option selected disabled class="hideoption">Company
                                    (please check one)</option>
                                <option class="mm">RMG</option>
                                <option class="mm">LMG</option>
                                <option class="mm">CSC</option>
                                <!---<option>Option 4</option>
                                                                                            <option>Option 5</option>--->
                        </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" class="mm">&nbsp;&nbsp;Position Title<br />
                        <br /></td>
                        <td rowspan="3" style="text-align: center" class="mm"><select
                            class="selectmenu">
                                <option selected disabled class="hideoption" style="width: 10%">Check
                                    one</option>
                                <option class="mm">RMG</option>
                                <option class="mm">LMG</option>
                                <option class="mm">CSC</option>
                                <!---<option>Option 4</option>
                                                                                            <option>Option 5</option>--->
                        </select></td>
                        <td rowspan="3" class="mm"
                            style="text-align: center; width: 20%; margin-top: -20px; vertical-align: top">
                            ADOC<br /> <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" /> <span
                            class="text2">If ADOC-does<br /> position support UCMG?<br />
                                <input type="checkbox" /> YES&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input
                                type="checkbox" /> NO
                        </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="mm" style="vertical-align: top">&nbsp;&nbsp;Reporting
                            to<br />
                        <br />
                        </td>
                        <td rowspan="1" class="mm"
                            style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top">&nbsp;&nbsp;Full
                            Time<br />
                        <input style="" type="checkbox" />
                        </td>
                        <td rowspan="1" class="mm" style="text-align: center">TEMP<br />
                            <input type="checkbox" /><br /> Duration of assignment
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="mm" style="width: 20%"><b>UltiPro Supervisor
                                (timekeeping)</b><br />
                        <br /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4" class="mm">&nbsp;&nbsp;SECTION C - REASON FOR
                            VACANCY</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" class="mm">&nbsp;&nbsp;Last Incumbent Name<br />
                            <br /></td>
                        <td colspan="2" class="mm">&nbsp;&nbsp;Date Position Vacated<br />
                        <br />
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4" class="mm">&nbsp;&nbsp;SECTION D -
                            AUTHORIZATIONS (MUST HAVE SIGNATURES)</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="mm" style="width: 5%; vertical-align: top">&nbsp;&nbsp;Date<br />
                            <br />
                        <br /></td>
                        <td class="mm" style="width: 15%; vertical-align: top">&nbsp;&nbsp;Hiring
                            Manager (signature required)<br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        </td>
                        <td class="mm" style="width: 5%; vertical-align: top">&nbsp;&nbsp;Date<br />
                        <br />
                        <br /></td>
                        <td class="mm" style="width: 30%; vertical-align: top">&nbsp;&nbsp;Vice
                            President Human Resources (signature required)<br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="mm" style="width: 5%; vertical-align: top">&nbsp;&nbsp;Date<br />
                        <br /> <br /></td>
                        <td class="mm" style="width: 25%">&nbsp;&nbsp;VP or Medical
                            Director or Dep (signature required)<br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        </td>
                        <td class="mm" style="width: 5%; vertical-align: top">&nbsp;&nbsp;Date<br />
                        <br /> <br /></td>
                        <td class="mm" style="width: 30%; vertical-align: top">&nbsp;&nbsp;COO/CFO<br />
                        <br />
                        <br /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="mm" colspan="4">SECTION E - POSITION JUSTIFICATION
                            (must be completed for ALL positions)</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="mm" style="font-style: italic; background-color: white">To
                            facilitate the approval of this JAN please provide specific
                            business criteria as to why this position needs to be added or
                            replaced.<br />
                        <div style="height: 180px"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <br />
```

Below is the CSS:

```
    /* top elements */
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }


body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font: .70em/1.5em  Verdana, Tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #666666; 
    background: #A9BAC3 url(bg.gif) repeat-x;
    text-align: center;
}

/* links */
a { 
    color: #4284B0;
    background-color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: #9EC068;
    background-color: inherit;
}

/* headers */
h1, h2, h3 {
    font: bold 1em 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Sans-serif;
    color: #333;    
}
h1 { font-size: 1.5em; color: #6297BC; } 
h2 { font-size: 1.4em; text-transform:uppercase;}
h3 { font-size: 1.3em; }
h4 { font-size: 1.1em; color: #6297BC; } 
h5 { font-size: 1.2em; color: red; font-weight:bold }
h6 { font-size: 1.1em; font-weight:bold  } 

p.data {
padding:0 0 0 0
}

p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin: 10px 15px;
}

  border-left: 4px solid #4284B0; 
}
acronym {
  cursor: help;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
}

/* form elements */
form {
    margin:10px; padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #f2f2f2; 
    background-color: #FAFAFA; 
}

form.a {
    margin:10px; padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #f2f2f2; 
    background-color: white; 
     
}

form.b {
    margin:10px; padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #f2f2f2; 
    border-color:#333333;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
}

form.c {
    margin:10px; padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #f2f2f2; 
    background-color: white; 
    border:inherit;
    border:groove;
    border-color:#000000;
     
}

form.d {
    margin:10px; padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #f2f2f2; 
    background-color: white; 
    border-color:#000000;
    width:500px;
     
}

form.e {
    margin:10px; padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #f2f2f2; 
    background-color: white; 
    border-color:#000000;
    width:800px;
     
}
    
form.f {
    margin:10px; padding: 0;
    border: 0px ; 
    background-color: white; 
    border-color:#000000;
    width:500px;
     
}

form.g {
    margin:10px; padding: 0;
    background-color: white; 
    border-color:#f2f2f2;
    width:600px;
     
}

 


form.h {
    margin:10px; padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;  
    background-color: white; 
    border-color:#000000;
    width:700px;
     
}

form.i {
    margin:5px; padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;  
    background-color: white; 
    border-color:#000000;
    width:780px;
     
}

form.j {
    margin:0px; padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;  
    background-color: white; 
    border-color:#000000;
    width:800px;
     
}
label {
    display:block;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin:5px 0;
}
input {

    padding: 2px;
    border:1px solid #D7D7D7;
    font: normal 1em Verdana, sans-serif;
    color:#000;
}

input.a {
    padding: 4px;
    border:1px solid #D7D7D7;
    font: normal 1em Verdana, sans-serif;
    color:#000;
}

input.b {
    padding: 4px;
     
    font: normal 1em Verdana, sans-serif;
    color:#000;
    display: none !important;

}

input.border {
    padding: 2px;
    border:1px solid #999999;
    font: normal 1em Verdana, sans-serif;
    color:#777;
}

input.borderB {
    padding: 6px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    font: normal 1em Verdana, sans-serif;
    color:black;
     
}

input.borderC {
    padding: 6px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    font: normal 1em Verdana, sans-serif;
    color:black;
    font-size:12px
     
}


input.borderD {
    padding: 2px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    font: normal 1em Verdana, sans-serif;
    color:black;
    font-size:14px
     
}

input.borderE {
    padding: 4px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    font: normal 1em Verdana, sans-serif;
    color:black;
    font-size:11px
     
}

input.textbox{
    padding: 2px;
    border:1px solid #999999;
    font: normal 1em Verdana, sans-serif;
    color:#777;
}
textarea {
    width:300px;
    padding:2px;
    font: normal 1em Verdana, sans-serif;
    border:1px solid #eee;
    height:100px;
    display:block;
    color:#777;
}

textarea.a {
    border:none;
    background-color:transparent;
    width:300px;
    padding:1px;
    font: normal 1em Verdana, sans-serif;
    height:50px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: none;

     
}

textarea.b{
    background-color:#f2f2f2;  
    width:250px;
    padding:1px;
    font: normal 1em; color:#000000; font-family:Calibri; font-size:12px;
    height:75px;
    overflow: auto;
    border:inherit;
    border:groove;
    border-color:#000000;
     
}

/* search form */
form.searchform {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
form.searchform input.textbox { 
    margin: 0; 
    width: 120px;
    border: 1px solid #9EC630; 
    background: #FFF;
    color: #333; 
    height: 14px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
form.searchform input.button { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 2px 3px; 
    font: bold 12px Arial, Sans-serif; 
    background: #FAFAFA;
    border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
    color: #777;    
    width: 60px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

form.searchform input.textboxa { 
    margin: 0; 
    width: 120px;
    border: 1px solid #9EC630; 
    background: #FFF;
    color: #333; 
    background-image:url(googlesm.gif);
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height: 14px;
    vertical-align: top;
}


/***********************
      LAYOUT
************************/
#wrap {
    background: #FFF;
    width: 820px; height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    text-align: left;
}

#wrapnew {
    background: #FFF;
    width: 1000px; height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    text-align: left;
}

#content-wrap {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;  
    background: #FFF;
}

/* header */
#header {
    position: relative;
    height: 85px;   
    background: #000 url(headerbg.gif) repeat-x 0% 100%;    
}
#header h1#logo {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    font: bolder 2.8em 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    top: 0; left: 5px;  
}
#header h2#slogan {
    position: absolute;  
    top:37px; left: 45px;
    color: #666666;
    text-indent: 0px;
    font: bold 11px Tahoma, 'trebuchet MS', Sans-serif; 
    text-transform: none;   
}
#header form.searchform {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: -12px;   
}

/* main */
#main {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 50%;     
}

#mainland {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 95%;     
}
 #mainPhoto2 {
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;        
}

* html body #sidebar ul.sidemenu a { height: 18px; }
/* menu tabs */
#header ul {
    z-index: 999999;
    position: absolute;
   margin:0; padding: 0;
   list-style:none;
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 6px !important; bottom: 5px;
    font: bold 13px  Arial, 'Trebuchet MS', Tahoma, verdana,  sans-serif;   
}
#header li {
   display:inline;
   margin:0; padding:0;
}
#header a {
   float:left;
   background: url(tableft.gif) no-repeat left top;
   margin:0;
   padding:0 0 0 4px;
   text-decoration:none;
}
#header a span {
   float:left;
   display:block;
   background: url(tabright.gif) no-repeat right top;
   padding:6px 15px 3px 8px;
   color: #FFF;
}
/* Commented Backslash Hack hides rule from IE5-Mac \*/
#header a span {float:none;}
/* End IE5-Mac hack */
#header a:hover span {
    color:#FFF;
}
#header a:hover {
   background-position:0% -42px;
}
#header a:hover span {
   background-position:100% -42px;
}
#header #current a {
   background-position:0% -42px;
    color: #FFF;
}
#header #current a span {
   background-position:100% -42px;
    color: #FFF;
}
/* end menu tabs */

/* alignment classes */
.float-left  { float: left;
border: none;
 }
.float-right {  float: right; }
.align-left  {  text-align: left; }
.align-right {  text-align: right; }

/* additional classes */
.clear { clear: both; }
.green {    color: #9EC630; }
.gray  {    color: #BFBFBF; }
.black  {   color: black; }
.red  { color: red; }

#about {
    position: absolute;
    left: 369px;
    top: 15px;
    height: 296px;
    width: 287px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px;
}
/* For Vision */
#contCol .regalList li { 
    background:url(../../images/regal_bullet.GIF) 0 12px no-repeat; 
    padding:8px 0 0 20px;
} 

    /* the Default theme */
            *::-moz-any-link br,*:-moz-any-link br {
            /*a workarround for mozilla*/
            display:none;
            }
            div#menuold * {
                border-collapse: collapse; /*removes the cell-borders*/
                cursor: pointer; /*because IE displays the text cursor if the link is inactive*/
            }
            
            div#menuold {
               /*background: #efebde;*/
               height: 15px;
               white-space: nowrap;
               width: 10%;
            }
            div#menuold .a {
              /* background: #F5F5DC;
               border: 1px solid #F5F5DC;*/
               color: #000000;
               text-decoration: none;
            }
            div#menuold .a table {
               display: block;
               font: 10px Verdana, sans-serif;
               white-space: nowrap;
            }
            div#menuold table, div#menuold table a {
               display: none;
            }
            div#menuold .a:hover {
               color:black;
               background: #7DA6EE;
               border: 1px solid #000080;
               color: #0000FF;
               margin-right:-1px; /*resolves a problem with Opera not displaying the right border*/
            }
            
            div#menuold .a:hover table#niv1 {
               background: #FFFFFF;
               border: 1px solid #708090;
               display: block;
               white-space: nowrap;
               position:absolute;
            }
            
            
            div#menuold .a:hover table#niv1 a  {
               border-left: 10px solid #708090;
               border-right: 1px solid white; /*resolves a jump problem*/
               color: black;
               display: block;
               padding: 1px 12px;
               text-decoration: none;
               white-space: nowrap;
               z-index: 1000;
            }
            
            div#menuold .a:hover table#niv2{
                display:none
            }
                
            div#menuold .a:hover table#niv1 a:hover {
               background: #7DA6EE;
               border: 1px solid #000000;
               border-left: 10px solid #000000;
               color: #000000;
               display: block;
               padding: 0px 12px;
               text-decoration: none;
               z-index: 1000;
            }
            div#menuold .a:hover table#niv1 a:hover table#niv2{
               background: #FFFFFF;
               border: 1px solid #708090;
               display: block;
               white-space: nowrap;
               position:absolute;           
            }
            tr, td, table {font-size:10px;font-family:arial, sans-serif, tahoma;color: #000; text-align: left;}
            select { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 1px solid #eee; color: #000000; background: #d8d8d8; font-size:10px;}
            select.a { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 1px solid #eee; color: #000000; background: #d8d8d8; font-size:11px;}
            select.b{margin: 0;border-width: 1px; padding: 1px;font-weight: normal;font-size: 11px;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background-color: #F8F8F8;color: #000;}
            select.c{margin: 0;border-width: 1px; padding: 1px;font-weight: normal;font-size: 10px;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background-color: #F8F8F8;color: #000;}
            select.bb{margin: 0;border-width: 1px; padding: 2px;font-weight: normal;font-size: 13px;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background-color: #fee4ac;color: #000;}
            select.bc{margin: 0;border-width: 1px; padding: 2px;font-weight: normal;font-size: 12px;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;;background-color: #F8F8F8;color: #000;}
            select.c{margin: 0;border-width: 1px; padding: 1px;font-weight: normal;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background-color: #F8F8F8;color: #000; width: 150px;font-size: 10px;border:1px solid #69A3D3;height: 100px;padding-right:0px}
            
            .rdate { margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 85px; border: 1px solid #eee; color: #000000; background: #d8d8d8;font-size:11px; }
            TH {font-family:arial, sans-serif, tahoma; font-size:11px;color: #808080; text-align: center;font-weight: bold;}
            TH.a {font-family:arial, sans-serif, tahoma; font-size:11px;color: #808080; text-align: left;font-weight: bold;}
            TH.b {font-family:arial, sans-serif, tahoma; font-size:12px;color: #808080; text-align: center;font-weight: bold;}
            TH.c {font-family:arial, sans-serif, tahoma; font-size:13px;color: #808080; text-align: center;font-weight: bold;}
             
            Td.a {font-family:arial, sans-serif, tahoma; font-size:10px;color: #808080; text-align: center;}
            Td.b {font-family:arial, sans-serif, tahoma; font-size:11px;color: #808080; text-align: center;font-weight: bold;}
            Td.c {font-family:arial, sans-serif, tahoma; font-size:11px;color: #000; text-align: left;}
            Td.d {font-family:arial, sans-serif, tahoma; font-size:11px;color: #000; text-align: center;}
            Td.e {font-family:arial, sans-serif, tahoma; font-size:11px;color: #333333; text-align: left;font-weight: bold;}
            Td.f {font: bold 1em 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Sans-serif; color: #333;font-size: 1.1em; font-weight:bold }
            Td.g {font-family:arial, sans-serif, tahoma; font-size:11px;color: #000; text-align: left;}
            Td.h {font-family:arial, sans-serif, tahoma; font-size:11px;color: #000; text-align: center;}
            Td.i {font-family:arial, sans-serif, tahoma; font-size: 1.2em;color: #000; text-align: left;font-weight:bold}
            Td.j {font-family:arial, sans-serif, tahoma; font-size:11px;color: #000; text-align: left;  word-break: break-all;word-break: break-word;}
            Td.jj {font-family:arial, sans-serif, tahoma; font-size:12px;color: #000; text-align: left;  word-break: break-all;word-break: break-word; vertical-align:top}
            Td.k {font-family:arial, sans-serif, tahoma; font-size:9px;color: #000; text-align: left; font-style:italic}
            Td.l {font-family:Trebuchet MS, Arial, Sans-serif; font-size:14px;color: #333333; text-align: left;font-weight: bold;}
            Td.m {font-family:arial, sans-serif, tahoma; font-size: 1.2em;color: #000; text-align: left;font-weight:bold;}
            Td.mm {font-family:arial, sans-serif, tahoma; font-size: 1.2em;color: #000; text-align: left;font-weight:bold; padding:2px}
            Td.n {font-family:arial, sans-serif, tahoma; font-size:11px;color: #000; text-align: left;vertical-align:top}
            Td.o {font-family:arial, sans-serif, tahoma; font-size: 1.2em;color: #000; text-align: center;font-weight:bold}
            Td.p {font-family:arial, sans-serif, tahoma;, sans-serif; font-size: 1.2em;color: #666; text-align: left;}
            Td.r {font-family:arial, sans-serif, tahoma; font-size:14px;color: #000; text-align: left; height:25px }
            Td.s {font-family:arial, sans-serif, tahoma; font-size:14px;color: #000; text-align: left; height:25px;font-weight: bold;}
            .checkbox, .radio {
    width: 19px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 0 5px 0 0;
    background: url(checkbox.gif) no-repeat;
    display: block;
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    }
    
    table.b {
    margin:10px; padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #f2f2f2; 
    
    background-color: white; 
    border:inherit;
    border:groove;
    border-color:#000000;
     }
            
.box {
background-color: #eee;
border: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #CC9999;
padding: 5px;
margin: 5px;
width: 400px;
height: 290px;
}

.vertical-line {
display: inline;
background-color: #000;
width: 1px;
height: 100%;
}
.negs {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
    border:#000000 solid 1px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
.negs tr th{
    border:#000000 solid 1px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    color:#000000;
    padding:5px;
    margin:0;
}
.negs .odd td{
    padding:5px;
    margin:0;
    background-color:#E4EDF3;
    border:#000000 solid 1px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
.negs .even td{
    padding:5px;
    margin:0;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border:#000000 solid 1px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.negs .fixed td{
    padding:5px;
    margin:0;
    color:#ACA899;
    background-color:#ECE9D8;
    border:#000000 solid 1px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

/* tables */
table.tablesorter {
    font-family:arial;
    background-color: #CDCDCD;
    margin:10px 0pt 15px;
    font-size: 8pt;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr th, table.tablesorter tfoot tr th {
    background-color: #e6EEEE;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    font-size: 8pt;
    padding: 4px;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .header {
    background-image: url(bgsort.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
    cursor: pointer;
}
table.tablesorter tbody td {
    color: #3D3D3D;
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    vertical-align: top;
}
table.tablesorter tbody tr.odd td {
    background-color:#F0F0F6;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {
    background-image: url(asc.gif);
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown {
    background-image: url(desc.gif);
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown, table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {
background-color: #8dbdd8;
}
/* New Small Table */
table.tablesortersm {
    font-family:arial;
    background-color: #CDCDCD;
    margin:10px 0pt 15px;
    font-size: 8pt;
    width: 95%;
    text-align: left;
}
table.tablesortersm thead tr th, table.tablesortersm tfoot tr th {
    background-color: #e6EEEE;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    font-size: 8pt;
    padding: 4px;
}
table.tablesortersm thead tr .header {
    background-image: url(bgsort.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
    cursor: pointer;
}
table.tablesortersm tbody td {
    color: #3D3D3D;
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    vertical-align: top;
}
table.tablesortersm tbody tr.odd td {
    background-color:#F0F0F6;
}
table.tablesortersm thead tr .headerSortUp {
    background-image: url(asc.gif);
}
table.tablesortersm thead tr .headerSortDown {
    background-image: url(desc.gif);
}
table.tablesortersm thead tr .headerSortDown, table.tablesortersm thead tr .headerSortUp {
background-color: #8dbdd8;
}
/* CSS Document */
.ac_results {
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid WindowFrame;
    background-color: Window;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.ac_results ul {
    width: 100%;
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.ac_results iframe {
    display:none;/*sorry for IE5*/
    display/**/:block;/*sorry for IE5*/
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:-1;
    filter:mask();
    width:3000px;
    height:3000px;
}
.btn-style{
    border : solid 1px #638a00;
    border-radius : 3px;
    moz-border-radius : 3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow : 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow : 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    box-shadow : 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    font-size : 14px;
    color : #ffffff;
    padding : 1px 10px;
    background : #96c300;
    background : -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#96c300), color-stop(100%,#648c00));
    background : -moz-linear-gradient(top, #96c300 0%, #648c00 100%);
    background : -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #96c300 0%, #648c00 100%);
    background : -o-linear-gradient(top, #96c300 0%, #648c00 100%);
    background : -ms-linear-gradient(top, #96c300 0%, #648c00 100%);
    background : linear-gradient(top, #96c300 0%, #648c00 100%);
    filter : progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#96c300', endColorstr='#648c00',GradientType=0 );

}

table.z { 
        width: 100%; 
        border-collapse: collapse; 
    }
    /* Zebra striping */
    tr:nth-of-type(odd) { 
        background: #eee; 
    }
    th.z { 
        background: #333; 
        color: white; 
        font-weight: bold; 
    }
    td.z, th.z { 
        padding: 6px; 
        border: 1px solid #ccc; 
        text-align: left; 
    }
    
    /*07/01/2016 JAN STYLING*/
        
        /*.dateCorner{
            border:1px solid black;
            height:40px; width:140px;
            float:right; font-weight:bold;
            padding: 0 0 0 5px; margin-left:2em;
            margin-right:1em;
        }       
        a{
            text-decoration:none;
            color:black;
        }
```

Any help would be appreciate, thanks

Comment: Can you format your HTML a little better to make it easier to see any syntax errors, and try and narrow down the code posted to be a [Minimum, Complete and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Also consider using jsfiddle.net to provide an example.

Comment: so where that thing should put? give me the exactly layout

Comment: @Fiido93 The td tag that contains TEMP should be next to the td that contains Full time

Comment: A very quick examination of the HTML shows you've got varying table `colspan` counts and actual columns. I see a row containing a cell with `colspan="4"` but preceding that row there is a row with only 3 columns.... so....

Comment: @Scott Okay, so your so mean that I need to add another row and that should fix the issue?

Comment: All table rows must have the same number of columns. Either by using `colspan="x"` or multiple `<td>` tags.

Comment: @Scott so yes, by add the same amount of columns to rows, it would allow the td tag with TEMP to be along side with td that contains FULL TIME

Answer (score 0):

Is everything else exactly how it's supposed to be? The area around those boxes don't quite seem to flow.

If I the rowspan on the 2 TDs that are 3 to a 1, it looks better but again, not sure exactly what the final product should be.

```
<tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="mm">&nbsp;&nbsp;Position Title<br />
                    <br /></td>
                    <td rowspan="3" style="text-align: center" class="mm"><select
                        class="selectmenu">
                            <option selected disabled class="hideoption" style="width: 10%">Check
                                one</option>
                            <option class="mm">RMG</option>
                            <option class="mm">LMG</option>
                            <option class="mm">CSC</option>
                            <!---<option>Option 4</option>
                                                                                        <option>Option 5</option>--->
                    </select></td>
                    <td rowspan="3" class="mm"
                        style="text-align: center; width: 20%; margin-top: -20px; vertical-align: top">
                        ADOC<br /> <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" /> <span
                        class="text2">If ADOC-does<br /> position support UCMG?<br />
                            <input type="checkbox" /> YES&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input
                            type="checkbox" /> NO
                    </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jng8uyu3/

Comment: Yes, everything else is where it suppose to be.The final product, like I mentioned, is I would like the TD that holds td to be next to the td that contains full time

Comment: And what about the Check One and ADOC boxes? Should they be just as long? Because that box needs somewhere to go.


See updated jsfiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/jng8uyu3/2/

Comment: @dany2327 correct, it is going to remain at the position they are at.

Comment: You only have 4 columns though, and because you already have 2 columns (reporting to, and full time) and then the row above it with 2 rowspan=3 that takes the last 2 columns available in that row, so something has to change.  

Look at https://jsfiddle.net/jng8uyu3/4/

Will this work? The only thing changed is the rowspan of the select one box from 3 to 1.  

If not, can you tell me exactly what it is it should look like? 
Alternatively, if everything has to stay EXACTLY as is, you could add the temp checkbox to the same TD like:
https://jsfiddle.net/jng8uyu3/5/

Comment: Right but Temp would not be above the check on box, but rather underneath Position title.

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer about which of my jsfiddles you are talking about?    Can I ask, do you know css and html? I'm guessing from the incredible verbosity and poor standards adherence that this was generated code.

Comment: I am new to both and what I mean is the second fiddle i guess would be the closest